Unable to setup Mercure with docker and Nginx(404 Not Found)
I’m trying to setup a project with Mercure. My project is a symfony for 7 version.
In that project, only mercure is setting up with docker, but the rest of the application, like nginx, database or symfony are not in docker. After tring many solution, i was not be able to found out the solution. Actualy with my setup, i get a 404 Not found error (response by nginx and not symfony)> Here is my code:
# - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: flex_mercure
    ports:
      -  "3000:3000"
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ':3000'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      # Set the URL of your Symfony project (without trailing slash!) as value of the cors_origins directive
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
        cors_origins https://flex-test.xyz
        use_forwarded_headers "1"
    # Comment the following line to disable the development mode
    #command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

volumes:

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  #database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

My .env
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
# See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html#configuration
# The URL of the Mercure hub, used by the app to publish updates (can be a local URL)
MERCURE_URL=http://127.0.0.1/mercure/.well-known
# The public URL of the Mercure hub, used by the browser to connect
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://127.0.0.1/mercure/.well-known
# The secret used to sign the JWTs
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!"
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

and my nginx config:
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name flex-test.xyz;
    root /var/www/flex/flex-v2/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /mercure/.well-known {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/mercure/.well-known;
        proxy_read_timeout 24h;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        ## Be sure to set USE_FORWARDED_HEADERS=1 to allow the hub to use those headers ##
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        internal;
    }


    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
    # location /bundles {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    # }

    #location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # when using PHP-FPM as a unix socket
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;

        # when PHP-FPM is configured to use TCP
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        #include fastcgi_params;

        # when PHP-FPM is configured to use TCP
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        #include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        # Caveat: When PHP-FPM is hosted on a different machine from nginx
        #         $realpath_root may not resolve as you expect! In this case try using
        #         $document_root instead.
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://example.com/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        #internal;
    #}

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/flex_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/flex_access.log;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/flex-test.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/flex-test.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = flex-test.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name flex-test.xyz;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


Amy idea will be helpfull
I have try changing 127.0.0.1 by the name of my local docker, but Nginx told me that he can not resolve the name. Also, when i try to do a get with the url that is in my Nginx conf "https://flex-test.xyz/mercure/.well-known", i get a 404 error(Not found responding by Nginx itself), and if i do a mistake in that url "https://flex-test.xyz/mercure/{misstakeUrl}" i got a 404 responding by Symfony.

You should use the mercure host instead of 127.0.0.1
.env
MERCURE_URL=http://mercure/.well-known/mercure
# The public URL of the Mercure hub, used by the browser to connect
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://flex-test.xyz/mercure/.well-known/mercure

nginx config
...

location /mercure/.well-known {
    proxy_pass http://mercure:3000/.well-known/mercure;
    proxy_read_timeout 24h;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    ## Be sure to set USE_FORWARDED_HEADERS=1 to allow the hub to use those headers ##
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

...


Hello @Artem! Thank you for your answer... I don't know if it could work, but i already found a solution. see the answer of my question below... Thank's

I finaly found the solution. The Problem was the url for mercure in my .env and my nginx config. So i would explain. The url using by the mercure hub internaly is /.well-known/mercure, so and other url will not work. That wy in my Nginx config, in the proxy pass, i have use localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure, and the same url in my env (MERCURE_URL = http:://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure and the public mercure url for the broswer tho connect https://mydomain.xyz/.well-known/mercure) as you can see below:
Nginx
# Configuration for Mercure service
    location /mercure {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # URL du service Mercure
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_send_timeout 10s;
        proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    }

    # Configuration for  the route /.well-known/mercure
    location /.well-known/mercure {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_send_timeout 10s;
        proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    }


.env config
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
MERCURE_URL=http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=https://flex-test.xyz/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET='!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###


Docker config
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  #database:
  # image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
  #  environment:
  #    POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
  #    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
  #    POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
  #  volumes:
  #    - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your d>
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: flex_mercure
    ports:
      -  "3000:3000"
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ':3000'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
      # Set the URL of your Symfony project (without trailing slash!) as value of the cors_origins directive
      MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
        cors_origins *
        anonymous
        #use_forwarded_headers "1"
    # Comment the following line to disable the development mode
    #command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  #database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###


Hope that this answer will help some one else....
